# Split an image up into quadrants or splice image into multiple?

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

So I have one image that on paper they were drawing lines/circles on particular areas of the image that they had designated certain sides as area 1-4, then 5-6 in the center and then a few specific spots as area 7.  They wanted to make this digital.  So I put the image on a win form, made it so they can create lines and circles (eventually I'll have it so the lines are measured and stored in an array)  However along with storing that I need to store what number area the line/circle was created in for tracking purpose so they can look back later to see where the majority of, in this case flaws, are being circled on the image. (The image represents a real machine part).  So right now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to designate certain areas of this image as area 1-4, 5,6 (and multiple 7's).

Is it better to split each area up into its own photo and piece them together like a puzzle?  Or is there a better way in code to do this leaving 1 image to work with?

Comment: Any suggestions.  Not looking for work to be done, but a method that would be best that I can research and figure out how to do.

Comment: Unless splicing an image and using multiple pictureboxes is the best method then I'll get to work on that.